# The Javascript Syntax Highlighter Upsets Me

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Give me the liberty to disable this problematic syntax highlighting script, please.  It does more harm for me than good.

Comment: What is so problematic about it? I don't notice anything wrong with the results of it.

Comment: It's weak on several languages like VB, even sql somewhat.

Comment: It's also just plain terrible on Perl.

Comment: @Brad: <insert cheap shot about Perl here>.

Comment: Way I seen it now: "user130648 request to make javascript syntax highlighter to upset". I think title could use some rewording.

Answer (score 5):

Use `<pre>` instead.

```
$(function(){
  $("div.someBox").remove();
});
```

vs

```
$(function(){
  $("div.someBox").remove();
});
```

If you wanated to disable this, you could do so with a greasemonkey script and firefox. You'd have to get the $.text() value of the pre.prettyprint, and then replace the pre.prettyprint with code tags.

Comment: Does PRE stop the Javascript syntax highlighter from highlighting it on window.onload?

Comment: How can I get other people to do this so when I open a question it doesnt screw everything up?

Comment: The service used to highlight code only works on the `<code>` tags if I'm not mistaken, so you should use the `<pre>` tags when you want to display code without having it highlighted. If you're experiencing serious problems with the rendering, you should probably consider submitting a bug-report.

Comment: When I copy it, it all gets scrunched into one line.  It converts string literal &nbsp; in my code into an actual space.  In one answer, my HTML decoding code snippet ended up removing every space from the given string, instead of nbsp;

Comment: That task should not be left up to the client machine anyways.  It's BS.

Comment: The OP wants to disable it on the local browser, not globally.

Comment: Greasemonkey! :)

Comment: Note that if you are trying to disable syntax highlighting for a preformatted block (that you are authoring), it appears that [`<!-- language: none -->`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) is [the preferred mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85379/formatting-preview-is-not-accurate-for-code-blocks-in-numbered-lists/85410#85410).