# Manually specify language for syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

This is a follow-up to a question I answered earlier ([Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/78312#78312)).

---

For most questions that have more than one language-related tag and those with fuzzy languages (for instance [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)!), there should be an option to specify which language to use in syntax highlighting because sometimes (and quite often too!) the language inference is wrong.

Take for instance the scenario I describe below.

When an answer is given in a language other than the "primary language" (which happens to be C#), the code is still highlighted as C# even if it isn't in that language!

**Scenario**

1. Take any question that has multiple explicit language-related tags.
   For example: [*Webclient.UploadFile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982299/webclient-uploadfile) which is tagged tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) and [webclient](/questions/tagged/webclient).
2. Try to answer the question with code that is different from the 'major' language.
   In this case, try answering the question with VB.NET code.

**Expected Results:** Code should be highlighted in VB.NET.
**Actual Result:** Code was highlighted in C#!

**Suggested Solution**
There should be a way to explicitly set the language for syntax highlighting.

**Edit**

It also turns out that asking a question with multiple explicit language-related tags can also give you wrong syntax highlighting!
You can try creating a new question with the following and observe the preview:

```
    //This is C#
    var someValue = GetValue();

some text to separate the two languages

    'This is VB.Net
    Dim someValue = GetValue()
```

Tag the question as follows (in the specific order) [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)

You'll notice without fail that the C# code gets highlighted properly and the vb.net code doesn't.

> **Disclaimer**
>   *All observations are based on the preview you get while entering the question or answer so my observed result might not be wholly right.*

Comment: The exact code that was not highlighted correctly would be a useful addition to this question.

Comment: If you try it out you'll see what I mean. Should you want to know what wasn't done properly off the bat, it's the VB.NET code that isn't highlighted properly. Prettify assumes both lines are comments/strings because the first line (`'This is VB.Net`) does not terminate its opening quotation mark.

Comment: I figured [Jeff's note](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) was about fragments (in both questions and answers), but maybe not: *and yes, there are plans to allow [an explicit override syntax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) but for now we want to try to get the defaults mostly correct before worrying about the edge conditions*.

Comment: As an aside: Jeff's above comment also links to the Google Code Prettify maintainer's [proposal on language specifiers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify). There, Mike Samuel suggests a first line like `#!css` or  `#!vb` in a code block. It's just a detail, but I guess ideas of *how* specifying might work might better be posted there.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This is now implemented. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

In addition to tag inference (a recent change), you can *manually* specify the language as a hint to [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

The spec is:

````
``` lang-or-tag-here
code goes here
```

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here

<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
````

You can also specify the hint to apply to all following code blocks with `language-all`:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->
```

You may use either a **tag** or a **prettify language code** to specify, though prettify language codes are always guaranteed to work regardless of what language the tag happens to be set to.

> **Available Language Hints Moved**
>
> Due to several lists of available hints existing throughout Meta, the entire list has been consolidated and moved to the following FAQ:
>
> [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: The iphone, mac, objective-c, cocoa, etc tags are all very active.  how about tossing "objc" in as a supported language?

Comment: @dave that would have to be filed against Google Prettify not us. Please see http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the `lang-` prefix automatically, especially since the comment already contains the mandatory `language` term?

Comment: @kop conflict with tags, which are also supported, see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/default and http://superuser.com/tags/default

Comment: I do not know why but I cannot explicitly set the code's language. I've tried this `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` and `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` on a question tagged `.net` and `c#` but neither of them worked. Could you please give a detailed explanation of how to go about this?

Comment: @alex just follow the instructions above.. you didn't have the code syntax comment in there at all. see my revision to your post

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for trying to maintain the many places/duplicates where this feature was asked for! To get a single point of reference: would it be okay if I would change most posts to refer to a single reference?

Comment: @Jeff: One more request... Can the question/answer preview be worked on so that the syntax highlight works there as well? The syntax highlight currently works only when a question/answer is posted.

Comment: Is it by design that each code block needs its own `<!-- lang: ... -->` comment? (Not an issue, but currently only the first block following the comment is using the specific language; blocks after that still use the language from the question's tags.)

Comment: This isn't exactly obvious, is it? I knew the feature got implemented, yet I had no idea how to access it.

Comment: Any chance for Windows command line / batch file (`.bat`) syntax?

Comment: I'm a coder for sure, but throw in a damn drop down. It's clear to me, the coder/user, and clear to SO/site what language is the intent, and doesn't require hunting down more knowledge.

Comment: @kit that "drop down" is the tags chosen

Comment: Er, yes, but I'm limited to 5 tags no? I'm using some to express intent, and some for language.

Comment: Could you add the common name for languages where the lang-abc isn't the name commonly used for the language? (e.g. lang-vb = Visual Basic)

Comment: Do you have formatting facilities for Postscript?

Comment: What about support gherkin for BDD from [http://cukes.info/](http://cukes.info/) ? See also [https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin)

Comment: are there a code for x86, ARM or MIPS assembly?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a question about, for instance, a specific branch of a tag (like "android-emulator" for instance) that does include some code, the standard language-filter that kicks in for "android" (java i presume :)  ) does not work. So a code-part that's far-from complete will not be prettified. I would say it would not be too strange to be able to hint the language!

Answer (score 0):

In cases that more than one language tag is present, prettify will attempt to infer the language. In these cases it will not always infer the correct language, but it seems to do a nice job from what I have seen.  I oppose this request as I do not think it is necessary.

Comment: When I ask questions on SO, I usually tag them with `c#` and `vb.net` because I work in both languages and I can quickly convert between both. In this regard, I'd not like code in my questions to be highlighted as C# when it is actually C#.

Comment: Also many questions are tagged with multiple languages, especially in the `.net` area. If the question is in VB.NET, someone may choose to answer it in C# and that throws off the syntax highlighter. (I haven't tested this out yet but questions in C# answered in VB.NET always get highlighted wrongly).