# Why isn't syntax highlighting working on this answer?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478910/nested-animations-using-canvas-and-javascript/5481346#5481346) is on a question that is tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) [animation](/questions/tagged/animation). When I am editing the question I occasionally see syntax highlighting applied to the code block. However, when I view the question/answer on the site I don't. How do I get syntax highlighting applied?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: @Chi: That question is older than the one I linked to in my answer.

Comment: @Jon: and the cause of everything (yours is linked in there as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh... Turns out, someone set the default highlighting language for [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) to `lang-html`. This was initially done for [html](/questions/tagged/html) as well, but reverted when it turned out this broke all those questions involving both HTML *and* JavaScript blocks. The system even warns you about it now:

> Setting a language to a value other than default should ONLY be done if the odds of a XML, Javascript, or HTML code block in the 
>   same post is very low,are you sure you wish to make this change?

...But apparently, [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) was overlooked when this was fixed for [html](/questions/tagged/html). And so combining [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) would break syntax highlighting for the script, since as far as the system was concerned, [html5](/questions/tagged/html5)'s `lang-html` was more important than [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)'s `default`.

I've set the default language back to... default.

Comment: Excellent find, nice work.

Answer (score 1):

The language key you need is `lang-js`. I've corrected your post. Note also, that it works by simply omitting the language specifier comment -- since [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is on the question, it defaults to that in this case.

For a full list of languages supported, see Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971).

Comment: Well, that doesn't explain why the JS highlight wasn't applied, in spite of the presence of `javascript` tag.

Comment: @Chi: Good point. Maybe it was just a glitch in the system. I edited one of my [sandbox posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/77317#77317) (10k only) using `javascript` as the language and it worked ok.

Comment: Glitch or not, the decision to *disable* the syntax highlighting altogether when there's no match on the tags was imo a poor decision.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the edit on the question. Hopefully automatic language detection will work better in the future, but for now that "hidden" list of languages supported and the magic comment needed to tag them is quite helpful.

Comment: @Phrogz: You're welcome. It's still a bit unclear why the highlighting didn't work in the first place, but at least we were able to fix it.