# Include information on manual syntax highlighting in formatting help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should include the information on the [magic comment and language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) needed trigger correct syntax highlighting, prefaced by a brief summary of [when the magic comment might be needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/78312).

*I was explicitly looking for this information when editing a post, was savvy enough to come and search on meta when I couldn't find it in the appropriate location, and I **still** did not find it on my own; it took someone else responding to [my plea for help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85280/why-isnt-syntax-highlighting-working-on-this-answer) to show me where it was.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was recently implemented (about two weeks ago).

On sites that have syntax highlighting enabled, the "magic comments" are now included in the formatting help page, as well as things like `[tag:syntax]` and (where applicable) LaTeX.