# Restore the extended details on the SO Editing Help page

Tags: feature-request, editing-help

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help used to have a lot of useful information hidden under accordions, but now it seems all the accordions are gone, along with the information that was in them.  This information is especially important for the SE additions to Markdown syntax since there is nowhere else to learn about them but SE.

I particularly miss the information about "[Syntax highlighting for code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85339/183358)".  While there is still an entry for it, it is missing [a list of available languages and the codes to use for them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/183358) as well as the explanation of the `language-all` feature. The current link to the [Google Code Prettify README](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) is not particularly helpful to someone trying to figure out how to format an answer. (It's also not confidence inspiring that the [other link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) points to a question on meta that is closed as "not considered a good, on-topic question for this site".)

I had a heck of a time figuring out that I had to put a blank line, then `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, then another blank line, and then my text in order to turn off syntax highlighting for a block of code.

I'd be happy with the old 'click-to-expand' format if you want to keep the page easily scannable, or even just link to something that does a better job explaining what to do.