# Why do I get nice Erlang syntax coloring in preview but not in the rendered page after I post?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, markdown-preview

While I edit Erlang code there is nice syntax coloring shown in the preview.

Once I post, the rendered code is often only black on grey.

Example: [Erlang pattern matching bitstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812902/erlang-pattern-matching-bitstrings)

Counterexample: [Simplest way to inform a local erlang node from a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901014/simplest-way-to-inform-a-local-erlang-node-from-a-shell-command) is colored nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preview just guesses what language you're using based on keywords. After it's posted, the highlighting is [tag-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

The [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) tag has no highlighting enabled because Prettify doesn't have an Erlang mode. Your counterexample actually has shell-script highlighting because of the [sh](/questions/tagged/sh) tag.

You can [manually specify the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) if you think the results look good enough.