# Mark two languages in one code block

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11052826/1111767). I reformatted it, to get better view and syntax-highlighting.

Referring to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/185025) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/185025), there is special markdown to force special highlighting. But that has one requirement: `<!-- language: lang-js -->` has to be surrounded by a empty lines and no indention. But as you see, there is mixture of JS and XML/ HTML.

So I tried in preview to get both, but it looks quite ... ugly:

```xml
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
```

```js
    var facebookLang = "en_US";
    (function (d, s, id) { 
        var js, 
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```
</script>
<div class="fb-send" 
        data-href="http://hain-celestial.ca/Recipes/PastaAndBeanSaladwithTunaDressing" 
        data-font="arial">
</div>
```

Which way should I choose to get it well-looking? Taking only `lang-js` results in this:

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    var facebookLang = "en_US";
    (function (d, s, id) { 
        var js, 
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-send" 
        data-href="http://hain-celestial.ca/Recipes/PastaAndBeanSaladwithTunaDressing" 
        data-font="arial">
</div>
```

Is it just status-by-design or did I miss a formatting hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't explicitly specify multiple languages for highlighting in a single code block.

However, if you use `lang-html`, prettify is smart enough to detect JavaScript in `<script>` tags and CSS in `<style>` tags, and highlight them accordingly:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    var facebookLang = "en_US";
    (function (d, s, id) { 
        var js, 
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-send" 
        data-href="http://hain-celestial.ca/Recipes/PastaAndBeanSaladwithTunaDressing" 
        data-font="arial">
</div>
```

Notice in this example, `var` and `function` are highlighted as JavaScript keywords, whereas the number and string values are highlighted as JavaScript literal values.

Some other languages like `lang-php` are compatible with HTML as well, so if you switched the `lang-html` hint above for `lang-php` you'd get the same result, because prettify is able to detect HTML and highlight it as such, even though you tagged it `lang-php`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to have one block prettify two languages so the proper thing to do as far as I can tell is to simply separate the code.

See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052826/facebook-send-button-displays-blank-flyout-for-french-version-of-page) now, I just separated the HTML from JavaScript - in the rare cases where JavaScript directly injects HTML through `document.write` this is wrong but usually that's not the case and there's no harm in separating.