# Can WPF tag highlight C# code?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Very often when questions are tagged as WPF, I find myself putting little snippets of C# into the answer (even if the question itself is specified in purely xaml, occasionally some C# makes a better solution).  However, after making my answer I always notice the C# code doesn't highlight, and I have to edit the C# tag into the question.  Couldn't it be implied by the WPF tag that both C# code and xaml code should be highlighted, or should I just continue to add the C# tag to questions if I have any C# in my answer?

Comment: If the question itself does not explicitly require the c# tag, then you can highlight it yourself using `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` in front of your code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Couldn't it be implied by the WPF tag that both C# code and xaml code should be highlighted?

No, because many different languages can be used for the code-behind (C#, F#, VB.NET, Python, ...).

This is why the [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) tag has no explicit language hint, so if there is no [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) tag it will highlight both [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) via language detection. If either of those two (or any other tag with an associated language) is used, only the associated language is highlighted.

So you can retag or as noted by Bart use an explicit hint:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) for a more in-depth explanation of language hints.

Comment: ehm, that works? I said [`lang-cs`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971)

Comment: @Bart: Yes, you can use tags as substitute. (If they have an associated language)

Comment: Are you sure that is how it works?  I just answered this question a few minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160618/mvvm-class-structure-and-layout-calculator-project/12183559#12183559 and it did not highlight my c# code until I added the tag.

Comment: @KDiTraglia: That's mvvm's fault, it has XML associated as well. Any tag with an explicit language will override the highlighting.

Comment: @H.B. Ha, you learn something new every day. :)

Comment: Ah I see, well question still stands, could it just always highlight both (to avoid these cases)?

Comment: @KDiTraglia: No, that is the whole point why it has no association, code in a WPF question can be XML + pretty much anything, ranging from C#, F#, vb.net to Python.

Comment: Oh that's a good point I didn't think about (in my box it's always C#).  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KDiTraglia: You're welcome, i shall add that to my answer...