# Possibility to add a feed of all recent answers to chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

Many beta-sites suffer with a problem of voting. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is one of them. We at Code Review have realized that it is hard to vote for answers that you're not aware of, therefore some of us (no monkeys named) posts a link to a recent answer every now and then in the chat.

Instead of us posting answer links in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) manually, which sometimes can give us an uneasy feeling of possible rep-whoring, we would like to add a RSS feed to the chat room to let the Stack Exchange bot announce **all** the new answers for us.

I understand that big sites such as Stack Overflow won't be needing this as there would simply be too much, but I believe that there are many beta sites in which this would encourage more voting which would lead the site one step closer to graduation. (Give us six to eight weeks of using this feature and I can come back with some data from the Data Explorer, which we're very happy about now that it includes beta sites)

Please add an official feed with a link such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/feeds/answers which can be added as a Chat Room feed.

Edit: I also think that answers for questions with a specific tag could be useful for chat-rooms. With a feed link like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/feeds/answers/java

Edit2: Not only would it be good to filter by tag, it would also be good to see new answers **for the meta site**, which also could use a feed. Not everyone visit the meta site every day, or as often as the main site, so feeding answers from there to a chat room will most likely increase meta activity and awareness. I'm hoping to see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/answers in the near future.

Comment: Note: we need a better 404 page.

Comment: Note: this feed was attempted, but doesn't seem to work (works in Outlook though): `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/codereview.stackexchange/answers&body=true`

Comment: When I'm in a room, it gives me a popup in the top left whenever there is a new post on that site's meta, or on the site itself. Do you not get that notification, or is there some additional benefit to it not being per-user, but actually posted in the room? For high volume times, this would seem a bit intrusive since oneboxing questions takes up a lot of screen real estate.

Comment: @jmac We're talking of ~20-25 questions/day, so I'd have them be posted by the StackExchange bot as chat messages. [The 2nd Monitor] is fed with both CR and Meta-CR questions; this post is about setting up a feed for main site **answers** (optionally for the meta site as well I guess). I might have that chatroom on my 2nd monitor all day at work, but I'm not going to hunt for answers - and I'm not alone. If new answers were posted in the chatroom, lots of answers would get more attention - and lovin'.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, didn't realize it was for new answers. I was thinking questions. Wouldn't this be even more cluttered depending on the site? Most sites get busy around the same time (early afternoon on weekdays US time), which is likely a busy chat time too.

Comment: @jmac - you are right, it would flood many SE sites, but **not** CodeReview. When it becomes a problem, it can be disabled. What is needed is the *option* to have it. The 'regulars' on [2nd Monitor] chat would all like this feature, and it seems many of the smaller sites would benefit if it was available. We *want* the notifications as it will improve site participation, moderation, discussion, voting, etc.

Comment: I see that I got a down-vote on this request, I guess that whoever down-voted is not an user one one of the SE beta sites that is struggling towards graduation.

Comment: Even on more active sites this could be useful when filtered with tags.

Comment: This seems overwhelming on most sites. I'm a mod on ebooks, which is also working through its public beta and needs more activity. On there, it would be fine. On most sites (and I'm a member of a number of them), it would drown out any attempt at conversation.

Comment: @EdCottrell Not as much if you filter by tags, or want to know about the meta activity. If it still would be too many answers when filtered by tags, then perhaps other filtering techniques could be added, or the feature doesn't need to be used - remember that this is an opt-in thing. The original idea is mainly for sites with low voting-activity, which I think would help them **a lot**.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224583/rss-feed-is-not-working-in-any-chat-rooms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since this is taking a while to get a response from, I've created my own chat bot that searches for new answers only and posts them to [the CR Answers chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers).

The bot is rudimentary right now, but it is a work in progress and gets the job done.

Comment: I wouldn't say "burn out".. it's just, well, if I skipped a day it's a pretty daunting task to catch up. Answers usually come in batches of anywhere between 1 and 4 or 5, which is very manageable. But as a human being I can't be doing that 24/7, so there's always a big "catch-up" to be made, that's the exhausting part....... Yeah maybe I'm starting to burn out.

Comment: Well, take the full +100 for helping me out!

Answer (score 14):

I've created a chatroom specifically for this: [CR Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers). Yes, the *Active Questions* view does a very good job at showing the **questions** that might have been...

- Posted
- Edited
- Retagged

It also bumps **questions** with answers that might have been...

- Posted
- Edited

And that is fantastic. The RSS feed being requested here would allow us to quickly (without bringing up the question and searching for *where* the activity might have taken place) locate:

- Spam & link-only **answers**
- Very short **answers**

Without monitoring the moderator tools (which, TBH, I rarely look at - maybe I need to start better using the tools at my disposal?).

But in the context of [getting the number of *questions with no upvoted answers* down](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission), such a feed also helps weeding out the noise (edits/retags) and allows us to avoid posting our own unvoted answers in chat ourselves (i.e. rep-whoring?).

By having *all answers* posted by the @StackExchange bot, we give *all answerers* the same visibility.

I don't look at the main page during the day; I don't browse the site either. But I always have the site's chatroom opened, at work or at home. An automated feed would give me a break!

Or are we just over-doing it? I'm hoping this question/feature-request gets more answers.

Why don't chat feeds work with stack2rss feeds?

Comment: Stack-a-holic, I am.

Comment: Stack2RSS author here - what do you mean by "chat feeds don't work with stack2rss feeds"?

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN great to have you here! I gotta say, that app is awesome! I mean, it *does* work in all RSS readers I've tried, **except** stack chat feeds; it would be *even more awesome* if these dynamic RSS feeds worked with chat feeds. You might be interested in [this recent conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers).

Answer (score 6):

For the [Rebol and Red](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) chat room, I generated an Atom feed of answers to questions tagged [rebol](/questions/tagged/rebol) on StackOverflow. The operative code (Rebol, natch) is fairly basic and can be adjusted based on volume:

```
do http://reb4.me/r/altxml ; xml library

feed: load-xml/dom http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/rebol

answers: collect [
    ; get the most recently *active* questions, adjust number based on volume
    questions: copy/part feed/get-by-tag <entry> 10

    foreach question questions [

        ; get question id
        question: find/match question/get <id> http://stackoverflow.com/q/

        ; load the individual question feed
        question: load-xml/dom join http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/ question

        ; keep the entries for each answer
        foreach answer next question/get-by-tag <entry> [keep answer/tree]
    ]
]

; inject the entries back into the original feed
insert clear feed/find-element <entry> answers

; revert to xml string
feed/flatten
```

This approach should work, though I've proceeded to adjust to filter out questions/answers older than a given number of days, tidied up the resultant XML, YMMV.

Anyways, the feed works as intended and even Oneboxes the answer entries as they come in!

Comment: Feel free to ping me in [Rebol and Red Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) if this is something you'd like to pursue :)

Comment: Sigh, StackOverflow—fix the [Rebol syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152002/why-do-unknown-language-ids-in-prettification-fall-back-to-guessing-instead-of) please!!

Comment: just to take the flake off from se... the syntax highlighting works with google codeprettify. In the markdown help section you can find a link to the homepage.

Comment: @Vogel612 There is a Rebol GCP highlighter (I contributed to it myself). It's not clear what the lag is for a highlighter having been created and it being integrated in SE.

Comment: I suggest you post a feature request then, or have it added to the standard GCP by asking a feature request in the google group: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list?can=2&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles