# RSS feed is not working in any chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat, feed

Consider the following RSS feed:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/codereview.stackexchange/answers

When added, to [this room's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12723/cr-answers) list of RSS feeds, no feeds ever show up. (Despite the fact that new items are continually being added to the feed.) This appears to be a network-wide problem since other Stack2RSS feeds in other rooms don't work either.

Since I can view the feed in other applications without problem, I can only assume that this is a bug.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216289/possibility-to-add-a-feed-of-all-recent-answers-to-chat-rooms