# Why is the "recent answers" feature so well hidden?

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting, hidden-features

For a long while, I've been wanting to find answers in the tags I'm interested in, because I like spending my votes.

I've given up hoping for a [chatroom-friendly answers RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216289/197901), so I ended up spending my votes on whatever I see that's interesting and good for the site.

Recently I was looking at a specific tag's top users page, and almost by accident, discovered a page showing the *last 50 answers* posted in that tag.

So the click path is basically this:

1. [Pick a tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
2. [Get to the *Top Users* page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/topusers)
3. [Get to the *New* tab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/new)

**Why is this page so well hidden?** *Questions* are obviously and understandably first-class citizens on all SE sites.. but a Q&A site is also about *answers*... and as a voter these can be hard to hunt - unless you *know where to look*.

Or is it just me? Could it be made *a little bit* more discoverable?

<sub>note: not too sure about the tags I'm using here - feel free to edit</sub>

Comment: The same list of answers could be obtained by searching for `[tag] is:answer` and sorting by newest (then you can bookmark the search page). The advantage is that you can do it for more than one tag at a time.

Comment: A lot of pages could simply be eliminated, and all these navigation links could be greatly simplified, if super-ninja-search™ was *the* way to browse SE sites...

Comment: I agree - I think I expressed a similar sentiment at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235102/215590