# Why can't we add this blog feed into our chat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, feed

After [various](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22119?m=22237000#22237000) [attempts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22119?m=24204366#24204366) ([and even once just now](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22119?m=24444488#24444488)) to add the feeds of [Lichess blog](http://lichess.org/blog) ([here](http://lichess.org/blog.atom)), which is in `ATOM` and should be supported, it seems to self-destruct and disappear from [the feeds tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22119/se-chess?tab=feeds) of the room information. Help?

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216289/possibility-to-add-a-feed-of-all-recent-answers-to-chat-rooms (some feeds just doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Atom _is_ supported. However, your feed actually has a couple of errors, namely the empty `<published>` and `<updated>` elements for the last post in the feed. I'll try to make a workaround to strip out those empty elements, though it's best if the feed is corrected, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed as of chat build 309 (already deployed as of current writing).