# Syntax highlighting razor views

Tags: feature-request, support, syntax-highlighting

I answered the following question yesterday

> [ckeditor and razor syntax templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353055/ckeditor-and-razor-syntax-templates/18717785#18717785)

I've noticed that the syntax highlighting of the razor code is somewhat broken.

Is there anything that can be done about this?

I don't think that there's anything wrong with the syntax since it highlights nicely in visual studio and executes without error.

I've checked the following post but can't see anything that mentions razor views

> [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/209611)

Comment: There isn't any Razor syntax highlighting. I wonder what's being used instead - if it's the XML highlighter, it's very confused.